# Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid on 'UserQuery.IItem<T>.ItemList'. 'T' is covariant

Tags: c#, covariance

Why the property get the error while the method can be compiled?

```
public interface IFoo {}
public interface IBar<out T> where T : IFoo {}

public interface IItem<out T> where T: IFoo
{
    // IEnumerable<IBar<T>> GetList(); // works
    IEnumerable<IBar<T>> ItemList { get; set; } // Error!
}
```

Error:

> Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid
>   on 'UserQuery.IItem<T>.ItemList'. 'T' is covariant.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You get the compiler error because you have a property getter (`get`) and a setter (`set`). The property getter has the `T` in it's output so `out` works, but the property setter will have the `T` in its input so it would need the `in` modifier.

Because you have `out` on `T` you need to remove the setter and it will compile:

```
public interface IItem<out T> where T : IFoo
{
    // IEnumerable<IBar<T>> GetList(); // works
    IEnumerable<IBar<T>> ItemList { get; } // also works
}
```

If your `T` is an `in` generic argument then the following would work:

```
public interface IItem<in T> where T : IFoo
{
    IEnumerable<IBar<T>> ItemList { set; } 
}
```

But you cannot have both (`out,in`) at the same time so you cannot have a co/contravariant property with a getter and a setter.

Comment: I don't understand this. You've related out,in to get,set. Why can't i use out, since out just means "this type or any derived type.". If B derives from A, then why cant I pass B to any property on the interface that requires an out A, since B will only be called as if it were an A anyway. 

What is the issue and what does in have to do with any of this? in says "this type or any base type". I don't want that as I'm expecting to use at least the behaviour set of A, passing an "a" will not cut it. So i wouldn't want "in"...but i do want to be able to set B into out A.

Answer (score 3):

The setter is not allowed, since if it were you would be able to do this:

```
public interface ISubFoo : IFoo { }

IItem<ISubFoo> item = //whatever
item.ItemList = new List<IBar<IFoo>>>();
```

which is not type safe.