# Can I have/use a field/property with a List<Class<T>> where T can be anything?

Tags: c#, generics, types, .net-4.5, covariance

### Original Question

I tried to make a generic class for my web requests

```
internal class Request<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : class
    where TResponse : class
{
    public Uri RequestUri;
    public TRequest RequestItem;
    public TResponse ResponseItem;
    ...
}
```

The types `TRequest` and `TResponse` are used to serialize and deserialize with XML, JSON, etc.

Now I want to store those `Request<>` in a list for queuing, caching and error handling. So I tried to declare:

```
private List<Request<object, object>> requests;
```

But then, I can't add anything to this list of requests because when I try:

```
var a = new Request<FooRequest, BarResponse>();
requests.Add(a);
```

I get:

> cannot convert from `My.Services.Request<FooRequest,BarResponse>` to `My.Services.Request<object,object>`

Is there a way to have a typed list of mixed typed requests (`Request<a,b>` and `Request<c,d>`)? Or a better approach to handle this?

I'm coding for .NET 4.5 (Windows Phone, Windows Store).

---

### First Edit

After many comments, a couple of unsatisfying answers, and a duplicate vote, I will review below what I tried based on all this:

- **Using an `interface IRequest<out T, out T1>`**

  Well, interfaces can't have a field. So I would have to cast the item of the list to an instance of `Request<>` to get access to what I want. I'm not sure how to write this cast to retrieve the two variants (`TRequest` and `TResponse`), help would be appreciated. But by systematically casting, isn't it the same as using `List<object>` in the end?

  Or I could set properties in the interface. But then it tells me I can't use the keyword `out`:

  > Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TRequest' must be invariantly valid on `My.Services.IRequest<TRequest,TResponse>.RequestItem`. 'TRequest' is covariant.

  So I could remove the keyword `out`, but when trying to add an item to the list it tells me again:

  > cannot convert from `My.Services.Request<FooRequest,BarResponse>` to `My.Services.IRequest<object,object>`.
- **Using an `abstract class BaseRequest`**

  Almost same issue, my base class can't have a field of type `TRequest` or `TResponse`; how to retrieve the two variants? I'll need to cast the item of the list. And so `List<object>` would be just as good.
- **Using generics wildcards**

  Doesn't exist and probably never will.
- **Check C# Covariance**

  Too vague answer provided and nothing to achieve it. Not even a [link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). I'm explicitly talking about `List<>` which is a covariant type. Solving this question is not easy as *man google*.
- **Checking thread: *A generic list of anonymous class***

  Absolutely not a duplicate, as question/answers are not meant for storing to a typed field/property:

  ```
  var list = new[] { a }.ToList();
  ```

  This is simply a `List<Request<TRequest, TResponse>>` and unfortunately, I can't declare anything with type `var` in a class, outside of a method.
- **`List<object>` or `List<dynamic>`**

  Again, not an example of `List<Class<T>>`. But let's try `List<Class<dynamic,dynamic>>`... Failure:

  > cannot convert from `My.Services.Request<TRequest,TResponse>` to `My.Services.Request<dynamic,dynamic>`
- **Checking thread: *[C# - Multiple generic types in one list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-sharp-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list)***

  This gets closer to my issue.

  -> Interesting, **Saeb** made the [same comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353126/c-sharp-multiple-generic-types-in-one-list#comment18362574_353126) as I regarding most answers with *it's all the same as* `List<object>`

  -> Now, **Bryan Watts**, with the least votes of all answers, found an interesting way to retrieve `TRequest` and `TResponse`. He declared this in the interface/baseclass:

  ```
  Type DataType { get; }
  object Data { get; }
  ```

  That solves the 'how to retrieve the variants' issue.

### First conclusion

As I will need to get the variants, I will need to implement some `Type RequestType` and `Type ResponseType`. Which means the `<TRequest,TResponse>` part will be useless. Which means I will go with a `List<Request>` only and the answer to my Stackoverflow question is: *no, you can't use/benefit from storing a `List<Class<T>>` in C#*.

---

### Second Edit

I failed at implementing Bryan Watts solution: apparently [it is not possible to use a runtime-type for generic methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298178/cannot-resolve-symbol-exception-when-passing-runtime-type). So I can't write `Deserialize<request.RequestDataType, request.ResponseDataType>(request)`. So I'm stuck: if I add my requests to a list of requests, I'm having runtime types and I cannot use the generic methods anymore. I didn't know generic methods were so inconvenient.
 :(

### Second conclusion

I will have a `List<Request>` and each `Request` will hold an `enum` for the kind of request, then I will switch on this enum and write down manually all possible request calls:

```
switch (@req.RequestType)
{
    case RequestType.FirstKindOfRequest:
        await Deserialize<FirstKindOfRequest, FirstKindOfResponse>(req);
        break;
    case RequestType.SecondKindOfRequest:
        ...
}
```

That's sadly the only way I could find to hold a list of `Class<T>` where `T` was supposed to be anything.

Comment: See [A generic list of anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612689/a-generic-list-of-anonymous-class)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you want a strongly-typed Request but a weakly typed list of requests? What is the original problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos everything about what I want to achieve is already written in the question, if you could take the time to read it carefully: "web requests with types for serialization, and I want a list of web requests for queuing, caching and error handling". ^_^

Comment: Turn `new Request<Foo, Bar>()` into `new Request(Foo, Bar)`.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty that will still create a list of a single class. That's not want is wanted here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman this probably won't even compile.

Comment: @mrida yeah, this may be the problem. Good point.

Comment: If you let `Request<TRequest, TResponse>` implement some interface, you could make a list of that interface-type.
List is strongly typed, so what you want is not possible. `Request<T1, T2>` is a different type than `Request<T3, T4>`

Comment: @rosko - you could make it compile, by changing `class Request{...}`

Comment: @HenkHolterman if you change it to `class Request{...}` then yes you are right but you didn't include this change in your comment.

Comment: I voted to open this q. The ones linked are not close duplicates.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're saying that the beginning of 'Later Edition'. But your problem may be here: "Or I could set properties in the interface." What you want to do is have the properties in the *interface* have only `get`, no `set`. Whereas the implementing property in the class can have both `get` and `set`

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic situation. Asked many times before too. I see two approaches.

-> The obvious choice would be to have a **non-generic base class/interface** which can account for all your request types, and then carry around `List<NonGenericRequest>`.

-> The second approach would be utilizing **covariance**. I see you face a few problem with it. I will *try* to solve it, one by one:

> Well, interfaces can't have a field. So I would have to cast the item of the list to an instance of `Request<>` to get access to what I want.

Do not use fields. Don't even think of it. Switch to properties. I gotta reiterate the point. Interfaces - in fact all public APIs - deal with properties.

> Or I could set properties in the interface. But then it tells me I can't use the keyword `out`

The problem is the *setters* of your properties. It breaks type safety. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484601/invalid-variance-the-type-parameter-t-must-be-contravariantly-valid-on-userq) for more.

> Which means the `<TRequest,TResponse>` part will be useless. Which means I will go with a List only and the answer to my Stackoverflow question is: no, you can't use/benefit from storing a `List<Class<T>>` in C#.

By now you can write something like `var requests = new List<IRequest<object, object>>()`. But this means you dont get strongly typed `TRequest` and `TResponse`. The solution is to get rid of generic type arguments `TRequest` and `TResponse` (ie your constraint `where T : class`) and include a more usable constraint. Something that *is useful to you*.

---

Combining them all, here we go:

```
interface IMessage //I will call it IMessage for now
{
    //implement whatever that make deserializing possible
}

class FooRequest : IMessage
{

}

class BarResponse : IMessage
{

}

interface IRequest<out TRequest, out TResponse>
    where TRequest : IMessage 
    where TResponse : IMessage 
{
    TRequest RequestItem { get; }
    TResponse ResponseItem { get; }
    //whatever fits, but only getters for out parameter types
}

class Request<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequest<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IMessage 
    where TResponse : IMessage 
{
    //you can extend interface properties with setters here
}
```

So now you can write:

```
var requests = new List<IRequest<IMessage, IMessage>>();
var a = new Request<FooRequest, BarResponse>();
requests.Add(a);
foreach (var request in requests)
{
    Deserialize(request);
}

void Deserialize<TRequest, TResponse>(IRequest<TRequest, TResponse> request)
    where TRequest : IMessage
    where TResponse : IMessage
{
    //have access to request.RequestItem, request.ResponseItem etc
}
```

*Note: For simplicity I haved assumed both `TRequst` and `TResponse` are similar types and hence both of them have evolved from `IMessage`. You can have separate `IRequest` and `IResponse` type interfaces for them.*

Comment: Thanks. I will consider it in a few days. PS: TRequst->TRequest.

Comment: No issues. What does TRequst->TRequest mean?

Comment: ctrl+f TRequst and you'll see ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I think that generics wildcards could help you there:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2633766-wildcard-generic

As this is not going to happen at least in the near future, I see three options:

- You can vote, wait, and hope Microsoft will adopt wildcards in generics...
- As Mrida commented, you can convert your code to use interfaces and then use C# covariance.
- If covariance is not an acceptable solution, you could define a non generic base class `RequestBase` with only the non-generic functionality, and make a list of `RequestBase` (**edit**: I think that this is HenkHolterman 's comment). Alternatively if you don't want to change the `Request` class you can define a non generic wrapper with the non-generic functionality.

Comment: I don't see how wildcards could be used here in a way that maintains compile-time type safety.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "compile-time type safety"? I guess you don't say that Java does not preserve type safety.

Comment: How are you suggesting wildcards could be used here, if they were included in C#? As far as I'm aware, the lack of wildcards doesn't restrict functionality in C# because you can just make the class or method generic instead.

Comment: The fact that you could bypass the lack of wildcards by generics, doesn't mean that wildcards are not a good solution too... Particularly, if you look at the first part of the question (the only one that was exist when my answer was written) you would see that his question is "Is there a way to have a typed List of mixed typed requests". Wildcards comes exactly to solve such problems. Notice that he is going to use it for serialization purpose, for which you don't have any cast and type safety.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of interface variance, by extracting a variant `IRequest` interface:

```
interface IRequest<out T, out T1>
{
}
```

and implement it in your Request class:

```
class Request<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequest<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : class
    where TResponse : class
```

This will allow you to create a `List<IRequest< object, object>>` that can store arbitrary `IRequest` instances:

```
var s = new List<IRequest< object, object>>();
s.Add(new Request<c1, c2>());
```

You'd still have to cast the contents of the list to a more specific class though if you wanted some type-specific behavior. This may or may not hurt performance in high traffic situations.

Another option would be to store the string contents of the Requests, or extract them to an abstract base class. A List of this abstract class would be more than sufficient for caching and logging. You could have something like this:

```
abstract class BaseRequest
{
    public string RequestContent { get; protected set; }
    public string ResponseContent { get; set; }
}

class Request<TRequest, TResponse> : BaseRequest
    where TRequest : class
    where TResponse : class
```

and you could still write:

```
var s = new List<BaseRequest>();
s.Add(new Request<c1, c2>());
```